# HMMlearn GMMHMM error

Tags: python, debugging, hmmlearn

I am trying to initialize several GMM's for use with the GMMHMM's gmms_ attribute. Each GMM instance has a different mean, weight and co-variance and serves as a component of a 5-component mixture for the GMMHMM. The mean, weight and co-variance are determined from a (5-cluster) k-means algorithm of the data-set I want to fit, where the mean is center of each cluster, the weight is the weight of each cluster and the co-variance is the - you guessed it - co-variance of each cluster.

Here is a code snippet:

```
X_clusters = cls.KMeans(n_clusters=5)
fitted_X = X_clusters.fit(X)
means = fitted_X.cluster_centers_
cluster_arrays = extract_feat(X, fitted_X.labels_)
print ('Means: {0}'.format(means))

total_cluster = float(len(X)) 
all_GMM_params = []
for cluster in cluster_arrays:
    GMM_params = []
    weight = float(len(cluster))/total_cluster
    covar = np.cov(cluster)
    GMM_params.append(weight)
    GMM_params.append(covar)
    all_GMM_params.append(GMM_params)

for i in range(len(means)):
    all_GMM_params[i].append(means[i])


model = GMMHMM(n_components=4, covariance_type="diag", n_iter=1000,
            n_mix = 5, algorithm='map')

for i in range(len(all_GMM_params)):
    GMM_n = mix.GMM(init_params = '')
    GMM_n.weights_ = np.array(all_GMM_params[i][0])
    GMM_n.covars_ = np.array(all_GMM_params[i][1])
    GMM_n.means_ = np.array(all_GMM_params[i][2])
    model.gmms_.append(GMM_n)

model.fit(X)
```

When I try to fit the model, however, I get the following error:

```
fitting to HMM and decoding ...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HMM_stock_sim.py", line 156, in <module>
    model.fit(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\hmmlearn\base.py", line 436, in fit
    bwdlattice)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\hmmlearn\hmm.py", line 590, in _accumulate
_sufficient_statistics
    stats, X, framelogprob, posteriors, fwdlattice, bwdlattice)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\hmmlearn\base.py", line 614, in _accumulat
e_sufficient_statistics
    stats['start'] += posteriors[0]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (9,) (4,)
```

I have never seen error like this before, its my first time working with sklearn and HMMlearn. How do I go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue using a random sample from a two-component Gaussian mixture:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.append(np.random.normal(0, size=1024),
              np.random.normal(4, size=1024))[:, np.newaxis]
```

So here's my take on why your code doesn't work. [`np.cov`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) treats each row of a given array as a variable. Thus for an array of shape `(N, 1)` the output is bound to be of shape `(N, N)`. Clearly, this isn't what you want, since the covariance matrix for a 1-D Gaussian is simply a scalar.

The solution is to transpose `cluster` before passing it to `np.cov`:

```
np.cov(cluster.T)    # has shape () aka scalar
```

---

After switching to a 3-D `X` I've spotted two more issues:

- `n_mix` is the number of components in a `GMM`, while `n_components` refers to the number of Markov chain states (or equivalently the number of mixtures). Note that you pass `n_components=4` to the `GMMHMM` constructor and then append 5 `GMM` instances to `model.gmms_`.
- Moreover, `GMMHMM` pre-populates `model.gmms_` so you end up with `n_components + 5` instead of 4 mixtures which explains the `(9, )` mismatch.

Updated code:

```
#      the updated parameter value.
#              vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
model = GMMHMM(n_components=5, covariance_type="diag", n_iter=1000,
               n_mix=5, algorithm='map')
#              ^^^^^^^
#  doesn't have to match n_components

for i, GMM_n in enumerate(model.gmms_):
    GMM_n.weights_ = ...
    # Change the attributes of an existing instance 
    # instead of appending a new one to ``model.gmms_``.
```

Comment: Unfortunately even after transposing the cluster array and then getting the covar, I still get the same error as above.

Comment: What is the shape of `X`? It is possible that the synthetic data set I've used does not match the one you're using.

Comment: Shape of X: (268, 3) i.e (N, 3)